# Why does this adj_matrix keep writing to the same row instead of iterating over the rows?

Tags: python, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to create an adjacency matrix from an adjacency dictionary.

Basically I want to create an empty matrix filled with zeros. Then iterate over every item in the adjacency dictionary and assign the correct weight in the matrix. But for some reason the code keeps assigning the values to the same row. I used matrix[][] to assign. Using python 3.7.

```
digraph = make_digraph() # A function that creates a class containing the adj_dict
adj_matrix = [[0] * len(digraph.adj_dict)] * len(digraph.adj_dict) # empty matrix
print(adj_matrix)
for source, destinations in digraph.adj_dict.items(): 
    for destination in destinations:
        print(int(source[1:]), int(destination[1:]), digraph.adj_dict[source][destination])
        adj_matrix[int(source[1:])][int(destination[1:])] = digraph.adj_dict[source][destination]
print(adj_matrix)
```

But it gives output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

0 1 4
1 2 1
1 7 2
1 8 2
2 11 3
3 4 1
3 12 2
4 5 1
4 8 3
4 14 2
5 6 2
5 9 2
6 0 1
6 10 2
7 9 2
8 9 2
8 11 1
10 0 1
10 7 2
10 9 3
11 1 4
11 12 4
12 2 1
12 8 3
12 13 2
13 4 2
14 9 2

[[1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2], [1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2]]
```

This does not make any sense to me. To be clear, for example the second iteration "1 2 1" I expected to write to adj_matrix[1][2] = 1. But it appears to write to adj_matrix[0][2] = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line is a problem

```
adj_matrix = [[0] * len(digraph.adj_dict)] * len(digraph.adj_dict)
```

You are copying the **same** list `len(digraph.adj_dict)` times and then every row in the matrix points to the list at the same location in memory, but each row in the matrix should not be the same. Changing it to list comprehension like this

`adj_matrix = [[0] * len(digraph.adj_dict) for _ in range(len(digraph.adj_dict))]`

should fix it if there are not other problems.